# Calculated distance between SKNodes does not change although they are moving

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, geometry

I am trying to find the distance between two nodes, specifically `rocks`. Now this is simple math; but I am running into a problem. I want to check to see if the `topRock` is within a distance, that distance is to be determined, of `btmRock`. The code I have is ->

```
extension CGPoint {
    func distanceFromCGPoint(point:CGPoint)->CGFloat{
        return sqrt(pow(self.x - point.x,2) + pow(self.y - point.y,2))
    }
}
```

Now in my update function I have ->

```
var updateTopTime : Double = 0
var updateBottomTime : Double = 0
var genInterval : Double = 2
var genOffset : Double = 3.5

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    moveBackgroundImg()

    //optional prevents generation if game is not playing
    //guard gameState == .playing else { return }

    if updateTopTime == 0 {
        updateTopTime = currentTime
    }

    if updateBottomTime == 0 {
        updateBottomTime = currentTime
    }

    if currentTime - updateBottomTime > genOffset {
        createBtmRock()
        genOffset = genInterval
        updateBottomTime = currentTime
    }
    else if currentTime - updateTopTime > genInterval {
        createTopRock()
        updateTopTime = currentTime
    }

    var distance = btmRock.position.distanceFromCGPoint(point: topRock.position)
    print(distance)

    if distance <= 10 {
        btmRock.position.x += 10
    }

    if holdingTouch{
        progressBar.progress -= 0.001
        voloc += 15
        plane.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy:  voloc)
        //plane.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: ))
    }
}
```

The problem is that `distance` returns `244.201193259997`. My `topRock` and `btmRock` are randomly generated as well as they move. Even when the nodes are moving the result stays the same. This is how I move my nodes ->

```
func moveBackgroundImg(){
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "BackgroundImg", using: ({
        (node, error) in

        node.position.x -= self.backgroundMovingSpeed

        if node.position.x < -((self.scene?.size.width)!){
            node.position.x += (self.scene?.size.width)! * 3
        }

    }))

    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "GroundImg", using: ({
        (node, error) in

        node.position.x -= self.backgroundMovingSpeed

        if node.position.x < -((self.scene?.size.width)!){
            node.position.x += (self.scene?.size.width)! * 3
        }

    }))

    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "TopRock", using: ({
        (node, error) in

        node.position.x -= self.backgroundMovingSpeed

        if node.position.x < -((self.scene?.size.width)!){
            node.removeFromParent()
        }

    }))

    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "BtmRock", using: ({
        (node, error) in

        node.position.x -= self.backgroundMovingSpeed

        if node.position.x < -((self.scene?.size.width)!){
            node.removeFromParent()
        }

    }))
}
```

I am confused on how my nodes are created randomly so they have different `x` and `y` points; but I am still getting `244.201193259997`. If it helps this is how my nodes are created ->

```
func setupRocks() {

    //create the base bottom rock
    var btmRockChoice = [SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rock")), SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rockGrass")), SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rockSnow")), SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rockIce"))]

    btmRock = SKSpriteNode(texture: btmRockChoice[mapChoice], size: CGSize(width: (self.scene?.size.width)! / 10,  height: (self.scene?.size.height)! / 2.2))
    btmRock.zPosition = -9
    btmRock.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width, y: frame.minY + btmRock.frame.height / 2)
    btmRock.name = "BtmRock"

    btmRock.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: btmRockChoice[mapChoice], size: CGSize(width: (self.scene?.size.width)! / 10,  height: (self.scene?.size.height)! / 2.2))
    btmRock.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCatagory.topRock
    btmRock.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCatagory.plane
    btmRock.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCatagory.plane
    btmRock.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    btmRock.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    //create the base top rock
    var topRockChoice = [SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rockDown")), SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rockGrassDown")), SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rockSnowDown")), SKTexture(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "rockIceDown"))]

    topRock = SKSpriteNode(texture: topRockChoice[mapChoice], size: CGSize(width: (self.scene?.size.width)! / 10,  height: (self.scene?.size.height)! / 2.2))
    topRock.zPosition = -9
    topRock.name = "TopRock"
    topRock.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width + topRock.size.width * 2, y: frame.maxY - topRock.frame.height / 2)

    topRock.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: topRockChoice[mapChoice], size: CGSize(width: (self.scene?.size.width)! / 10,  height: (self.scene?.size.height)! / 2.2))
    topRock.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsCatagory.topRock
    topRock.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsCatagory.plane
    topRock.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsCatagory.plane
    topRock.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    topRock.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
}

func createTopRock() {

    //You can make this number a class variable to increase the rate as the game progresses
    let randomNum = arc4random_uniform(2)

    //there is a 1 in 3 chance that this rock will get created
    if randomNum == 0 {

        let rock = topRock.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
        self.addChild(rock)
    }
}

func createBtmRock() {

    //You can make this number a class variable to increase the rate as the game progresses
    let randomNum = arc4random_uniform(2)

    //there is a 1 in 2 chance that this rock will get created
    if randomNum == 0 {

        let rock = btmRock.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
        self.addChild(rock)
    }
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    spawnDelayForeverTop = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.createTopRock), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    spawnDelayForeverBtm = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.createBtmRock), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

UPDATE: I believe it has something to do with anchor points but I am unsure.

Comment: Why would your distance ever change, your top rock and bottom rock move left at the same speed

Comment: all your rocks are created in the same position, there is no random x location, and arc4random_uniform(2) is 50/50 chance, not 33/33/33 (You only get 0 or 1)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon the timer that I have set up has a random number that it spawns them. So they are not created at the same time. They are created at different times with different spacing in between them. They also get removed from the parent when they leave the screen and get created again, and they also obey to the timer once recreated.

Comment: Your timer means nothing, it is a non repeat timer which means it only fires once, and it has a difference of one second, which means the top rock will either be 244 away from the left of the bottom rock, or 244 away from the right of the bottom rock, there is no variation whatsoever going on here

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I'm sorry I forgot to add some code in my update function. I just edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You topRock and bottomRock nodes are not actually the ones you see in your scene and are not added as children.  What you're adding to the scene are copies of these two "template" objects.  The position of topRock and bottomRock are never changed because they are not part of the scene's children (and I don't see any place in your code where you change the position of these two instances)